# How to put colors in a str.format() method string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this string:

```
form = '''
- {sha}: {message}
~> {commit_status_change}
=> {result_for_commit}
'''
```

Then I prepare parameters using `click` (or any other tool) for coloring:

```
params = {
    "sha": click.style(sha, bold=True),
    "message": click.style(msg, bold=True),
    "commit_status_change": click.style(change, fg="green"),
    "result_for_commit": click.style(result, fg="green")
}
```

Lastly, I print the string:

```
print(form.format(**params))
```

I want to make `=>` and `~>` symbols bold while keeping this neat form. How do I do it using python3?

Comment: Your title should describe your question in one sentence. What does "Colors in Python format string" have to do with "I want to make => and ~> symbols bold"? [Ask]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print colored text in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-in-python)

Comment: @mousetail: I my opinion this is *not* a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @martineau Just like in that question, the correct solution is to use the ANSI escape codes or any of the python modules that provide them

Comment: @Pranav: I have edited the question's title to make it better express the question, however since one could consider making the text bold effectively changing its color, I didn't change that aspect.

Comment: @mousetail: I think the question is how to use the escape codes in conjunction with `str.format()`. The OP could chime in here anytime and clarify things…

Comment: same as a color but just BOLD = '\033[1m'   but would never search that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ANSI escape sequences to make text bold:

```
form = '''
- {sha}: {message}
\033[01m ~> \033[0m {commit_status_change}
\033[01m => \033[0m {result_for_commit}
'''
```

On windows you have to call `os.system('')` to enable escape codes. Also, many terminals do not support bold, it might be better to use a slightly lighter color text instead, or use underline.